# Не работает клиент-сервер c#

Tags: клиент-сервер, nat, сетевое-программирование, c#-6.0

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение.
*Немного вводной информации:*
Клиент и сервер находятся в разных геолокациях, правда у одного провайдера. Сервер находится за двойным уровнем nat.
Клиент находится за одноуровневым nat. Обе машины к сети подключаются через роутер, но если сервер подключается через кабель, то клиент через wifi.

```
Сервер:
серый ip - 192.168.1.33
роутер - 100.58.58.71
внешний ip определяемый сайтами и stun - 88.201.201.201

Клиент:
серый ip - 192.168.1.54
роутер - 94.19.190.190
внешний ip определяемый сайтами и stun - 94.19.190.190
```

Проброс порта.  При чем на сервере этот же код срабатывает на ура, что видно на изображении.

```
using Open.Nat;
...
static async Task AddPortForwarding(int Port)
    {
        try
        {
            var nat = new NatDiscoverer();
            var device = await nat.DiscoverDeviceAsync();
            if (device == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Устройство NAT не найдено.");
                return;
            }
            // Получение внешнего IP-адреса
            var externalIp = await device.GetExternalIPAsync();
            b_realIP = externalIp.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Внешний IP-адрес: " + externalIp);
            await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, Port, Port, "  Gm service"));
            Console.WriteLine("UDP порт " + Port + " успешно перенаправлен через UPnP.");
            //проверка создания адресации
            foreach (var mapping in await device.GetAllMappingsAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Адресация: " + mapping.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (NatDeviceNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Устройство NAT не найдено.");
        }
        catch (MappingException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при создании порт-маппинга: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Отправляю ответ с сервера так:

```
static async Task HandleClientAsync(UdpClient server, UdpReceiveResult udpResult)
{
    try
    {
        // Получение клиентского адреса и порта
        IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = udpResult.RemoteEndPoint;

        // Обработка сообщения
        string response = "Hello, client!";
        byte[] responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);

        // Отправка ответа клиенту
        await server.SendAsync(responseData, responseData.Length, clientEndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Отправлен ответ клиенту: " + clientEndPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при обработке клиента: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить вот так:

```
static async Task StartClientAsync(string serverName, string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
            // Создание адреса сервера
            IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port);

            // Отправка сообщения серверу
            string message = "Hello  Server!";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, serverEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Сообщение отправлено на сервер: " + serverName + "  IP " + serverIP + "  ПОРТ:" + port);

            // Получение ответа от сервера
            byte[] response = client.Receive(ref serverEndPoint);
            string responseMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
            Console.WriteLine("Ответ от сервера " + serverName + ": " + responseMessage);

            // Закрытие соединения
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка клиента: " + serverName + ": " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно два вопроса:

1. Из изображения видно, что почему-то на клиенте не осуществляется проброс порта. Вместо этого выскакивает ошибка переполнения. И я не понимаю почему?
2. Клиент почему-то не получает ответ, в чем может быть проблема? Всякие там firewall и антивирусы сразу исключаются, это проверил в первую очередь.

**upd: изображение - это составное, не надо думать, что обе части программы запускаются  на одной машине. Просто решил вставить именно одну картинку, для  наглядности.**